# How to show total number of tests count with count of pass/fail in jenkins email

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to pull my automation code for website from github repository and then when builds finished I am receiving the email with details like project url,status ,duration.

What I want is that this email should show the below

**Total tests count
Pass tests count
Failed tests count
Skip tests count
Failed tests name if any**

**Platform**: I am using selenium to automate my website and testng with extent reporting

Answer (score 3):

For getting the count of `Passed`, `Failed`, `Skipped`, make sure you are publishing the TestNG Results under Post-build Actions (using TestNG plugin)

[image]

After that use Token Macro Plugin Tokens i.e `${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"}  ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"} ${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"}`   , to get the test count

Comment: Thanks Ravi this worked for me as well !!                                                                                is there any way to show names of failed test cases in same report?

Comment: The full list of available tokens, including TEST_COUNTS, is at _'Content Token Reference'_ link under _'Editable Email Notification'_ box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inbuilt email [template](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) which will send you the details of the tests. Below is the example of pipeline:

```
post {
  always {
    emailext body: ''
    '${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}'
    '',
    subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful",
      mimeType: 'text/html', to: "email list"
  }
}
```

This template is using JUnit, you can check the code in template and modify it for testNG or selenium.

Comment: Thanks for reply.but I am using TestNg and I don't Know how to make this work for TestNg.I need the Test Results like below                                                                                                 Test Results
Name: (root) Failed: 1 test(s), Passed: 231 test(s), Skipped: 0 test(s), Total: 232 test(s)

Comment: groovy-html.template is generic template so you can give a try and check if it works for testNG .

Comment: I have already used groovy-html.template but it only shows me Project Url,Duration,Date,Project Name and CHANGES from GitHub if any...Its not showing me TEST RESULTS..